# How to center Google maps driving directions between destination and source

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, driving-directions

I am using google maps URL commands to draw driving directions from a source to destination using the following commands:

```
    String geoUriString = "http://maps.google.com/maps?" + 
           "saddr=" + latitude + "," +  longitude + "&daddr=" + destLAT+ "," + destLONG;
```

then

```
Intent mapCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(geoUriString));
startActivity(mapCall);
```

This opens a list of options, when I choose google maps, it shows me the driving directions from the source to destination.

I have this question:

- how can I zoom the map out to fit the drawn path from source to destination? (because now it is zoomed in too much, the full path is not shown at once)

Comment: Which Google Maps API your are using? V1 or V2 (with Google Play Service)

Answer (score 0):

```
var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.49866955, 73.8957357166667),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);
```